# An equivalent of Single.merge, which runs each Single sequentially

Tags: rx-java2

The `Single.merge` documentation says:

> Merges an Iterable sequence of SingleSource instances into a single
>   Flowable sequence, running all SingleSources at once.

Is there a similar operator which creates a `Flowable`, which does not runs all `SingleSource`s at once but, instead, runs them sequentially - each one after the previous one completes?

Comment: [`Single.concat`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-) and its variants.

Comment: Does it have any benefits over the solution I've given in the answer with `Flowable.fromIterable(...).flatMapSingle(...)`?

Comment: Beyond that it does exactly what you wanted, in one operator instead of 2 and with less overhead?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
val singles: List<Single<String>> = // the list of Single
Flowable
    .fromIterable(singles)
    .flatMapSingle({ it }, false, /* maxConcurrency */ 1)
```